# Can't illuminate object from below nor changing light source from script

Tags: modeling, python, rendering, light

I've been using blender and its scripting capabilities for a machine learning project. The script generates a bunch of different sun objects and cameras (positioned close to the lighting directions) and then cycles through each combination to render the image.

I'm dealing with two problems:
1) The first question is for artists too. My object, being a satellite, is free floating in the model space and there's no obstruction of any kind for the light rays to reach it. Somehow, however, although everything is fine when the light comes from above the model, when the direction of the sun comes from below, the model is not illuminated at all. I really can't figure out what's wrong with it.

2) The other question is about the script. I have to activate the lighting one at a time, one for each iteration over the related cameras, just like each of the others were switched off. I've tried many solutions: when I try to deactivate and reactivate the light object according to my needs, renders seem to show like the last generated light always stay active and the others are unaffected; when I try to put to zero the energy of all the lights but the one I'm interested in, instead, rendered images are all dark.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated. Thank you everybody!

EDIT:
Sorry for not immediately providing the .blend file, but I didn't know how to do it. Here you have, thank you!

[image]

For those willing to take a look at the code, [here](https://hastebin.com/ipusunamoy.py) are the relevant pieces. The code is not very clean, but there you can see (commented out) some of the strategies I've tried. I think, anyway, it is quite useless to read it since the question is quite straightforward: I just need to know how to turn on and off a light source from the command line, if it is even possible.

EDIT 2: To better explain how the script should work, as requested.

I'm dealing with a machine learning project: that means that I'm NOT interested in any kind of animation or anything similar, I just need to produce many static images of the model at hand in different lighting conditions and from different POVs. With "many" I mean thousands of them, that's why I need to automate everything through a script.
So, the script I wrote should work like this: a certain number of light sources (Sun objects) is created and linked to the scene, by default they should all be switched off. Then the script cycles through them. In each iteration, one of the light sources is activated and a certain number of cameras are introduced. A nested for cycle then goes through all of the cameras, sets the compositing nodes to output the ID masks of the objects that compose the satellite (I need them too), and renders the different images. Than, the light source is switched off and the primary for cycle proceeds to the next iteration with another light source.
As simple as that, no need for fancy animations or anything. And everything works just fine but for the switching on and off the lights.

Comment: Welcome! TBH without seeing the script or your scene it's actually hard to give any good answer/advice based on this post. This is a q&a site so please add some screenshots at least to give us a chance resolving your issue. Also the site works best asking one question per post. Start here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour If you consider uploading your file please use: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ Thanks

Comment: I know the code is a mess, I'm sorry, but I wanted to leave it like that in order to show the various tries I had. Anyway, I've never written a single line of C in my life (nor I am a proficient python user), but I think you're referring to the fact that the main part of the script in enclosed in a function definition. That's simply because I initially planned to call it in another script, but than changed my mind and I didn't care about reformatting it.

Comment: I really don't know how is it possible since the file is the same, but for me the problem with the lighting is there. Both with Eevee and Cycles, when I hide and unhide lights from the viewport (clicking the little eye icon) only the lights coming from above are correctly previewed and/or rendered. Even if I delete all of the others from the scene. Is there some hidden setting I should change somewhere? I'm really a newbie with Blender.
The expression to toggle the light on or off is exactly what I'm looking for, but I wasn't able to find it up to now. Please, tell me.

Comment: Yeah, I knew that hiding an object in the viewport has nothing to do with the render, but as mentioned, the rendered viewport shading was wrong too. By the way, thank you, adding those other buttons to the window helped me understand that I should be able to switch the light on and off in the render using "bpy.data.object.hide_render = True/False". Still lights from below don't produce any effect (not even in the viewport) and most of the renders are dark (often even when light comes from above). I can upload the whole code to github if necessary.

Comment: No no, I was already using the rendered preview and the problem with the lighting from below is noticeable there. In your file the problem is not present though.
Furthermore, something is wrong with my script anyway, because results are as expected when rendering from within the program (e.g. hitting F12), I mean, they are coherent with what you see in the viewport and what you have hidden or not from the rendering. That's not true when rendering from the script, I guess I'm missing some render setting.

Comment: can you post the whole code? Without the entire thing it's hit and miss to debug.